# How to calculate cosine similarity for classification when you have say 10000 samples belonging to two classes have a bunch of samples

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, cosine-similarity

Does anyone have experience with using Cosine Similarity for text classification?  I see a number of articles on how to find cosine similarity between documents using Doc2Vec, Gensim, etc.

I have a classification problem (binary) where I want to try out the cosine similarity. I do know how to calculate it, but all the articles that I see only explain until the point of calculating it between two documents.

Right now, I am planning to do this.

1. Calculate the cosine similarity of 'my paragraph' (the one that I want to classify) with all samples in `classi` (their class is known). Then take the average (call that `avgi`)
2. Calculate the cosine similarity of my paragraph (the one that I want to classify) with all samples in `classo` (their class is known). Then take the average (call that `avgo`)
3. Compare `avgi` and `avgo` and then predict the class for 'my paragraph'

That sounds like a very manual way of doing it. Is there some better/widely used way of doing it?

Comment: What are the samples in (1), (2)? paragraphs or docs?

Comment: Each sample is a line of text in excel row.

Comment: @Sanny28 It seems that you want to use the cosine similarity to build a model that decides which class your paragraph belongs to? Why do you want to use this? Why don't you want to train a model that takes as input the paragraphs and produces the class (if you have a labelled dataset)? It's also not clear what your problem really is. Are you asking how to efficiently compute the cosine similarity when you have too many paragraphs?

Comment: Yes, what I want is a model that takes a paragraph and produces a class. I have done that successfully using other algorithms like RF, logistic regression and ANN. Someone suggested I try out cosine similarity too. I tried to get sample code from internet. All the articles that I see only explain how to calculate cosine similarity between two paragraphs. No one seems to explain how to use it do classification (compare with a set of paragraphs in both classes which are already classified). That is why i thought of the average method I explained in the question.